# find the sum of the given series.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

nC1 -nC3 +nC5- so on

i know, iota will be involved in here, but im confused as i think it depends whether n is odd or even, it turns out to be different in each case. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its binomial expansion for the real values of $$(1+i)^n=(^n_0)i^0+(^n_1)i^1+(^n_2)i^2+(^n_3)i^3+(^n_4)i^4+(^n_5)i^5+....$$
$$=(^n_0) +(^n_1)i^1-(^n_2)-(^n_3)i+(^n_4) +(^n_5)i +....$$

if we take the imaginary term from the series 
then it will become 
$$= (^n_1) -(^n_3) +(^n_5)+....$$